# Extract data from a log that contains certain pattern

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have an Apache log file with lines in this format:

```
192.168.100.1 - - [13/Dec/2018:15:11:52 -0600] "GET/onabc/soitc/BackChannel/?param=369%2FGetTableEntryList%2F7%2Fonabc-s31%2FHPD%3AIncident%20Management%20Console27%2FDefault%20User%20View%20(Manager)9%2F3020872007%2Resolved%22%20AND%20((%27Assignee%20Login%20ID%27%20%3D%20%22Allen%22)Token=FEIH-MTJQ-H9PR-LQDY-WIEA-ZULM-45FU-P1FK HTTP/1.1"
```

I need to extract some data from an Apache log file just in cases that the line contain the "login" word and list the IP, date and login ID ("Allen" is the login ID in this case) or save them in another file.

Thanks to your advice I am now using PowerShell to make this works, I have now this:

```
$Readlog = Get-content -path C:\Example_log.txt
$Results = foreach ($Is_login in $Readlog)
{
    if ($Is_login -match 'login')
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            IP = $Is_login.Split(' ')[0]#No need to trim the start.
            Date = $Is_login.Split('[]')[1].Split(':')[0]
            Hour = $Is_login.Split('[]')[1].Split(' ')[0] -Replace ('\d\d\/\w\w\w\/\d\d\d\d:','')
            LoginID = select-string -InputObject $Is_login -Pattern "(?<=3D%20%22)\w{1,}" -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches.Groups[0].Value}
            Status = select-string -InputObject $Is_login -Pattern "(?<=%20%3C%20%22)\w{1,}" -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches.Groups[0].Value}
        }
    }
}
$Results
```

Thanks to your hints, now I have this results:

```
IP      : 192.168.100.1
Date    : 13/Dec/2018
Hour    : 15:11:52
LoginID : Allen
Status  : Resolved

IP      : 192.168.100.30
Date    : 13/Dec/2018
Hour    : 16:05:31
LoginID : Allen
Status  : Resolved

IP      : 192.168.100.40
Date    : 13/Dec/2018
Hour    : 15:11:52
LoginID : ThisisMyIDHank
Status  : Resolved

IP      : 192.168.100.1
Date    : 13/Dec/2018
Hour    : 15:11:52
LoginID : Hank
Status  : Resolved
```

Thanks to everyone for your help.

Comment: So you want to return the entire line if it contains the word login?

Comment: does the sample data _really_ have all those `%20` encoded characters in it, or is that a copy/paste glitch?

Comment: @OwainEsau no. He says very specifically _"...and list just the IP, date and login ID or save them in another file"_

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Apache logs Really does contain the replacements.

Comment: thank you for the clarification! [*grin*] that makes the deal a tad more clear ... [*grin*]

Comment: How about using a [log analyzer](https://github.com/nielsbasjes/logparser) instead of rolling your own solution?

Comment: what is the login id here? `alien` ?

Comment: I don't see any attempt to find a solution by yourself or do any research. So this is off topic. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: are the asterisks part of the original text from the log?

Comment: Thank you guys for your advices. No, @Lee_Dailey, the asterisks are not part of the log line, there were to try to clarify the data needed to extract.

Comment: I will try it too, thanks @vonPryz. The intention with this is that the needed is related with a regular and scheduled procurement of data pushed in files, so an analizer usually dont have this attributes.

Comment: @npocmaka the user is Allen, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[replaced code using not-really-there asterisks in sample data.]*

**[powershell v5.1]**
this will match any line that contains "login" and then extract the requested info using basic string operators. i tried to use regex, but got bogged down in the pattern matching. [*blush*] regex would almost certainly be faster, but this is easier for me to understand.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
192.168.100.1 - - [13/Dec/2018:15:11:52 -0600] "GET/onabc/soitc/BackChannel/?param=369%2FGetTableEntryList%2F7%2Fonabc-s31%2FHPD%3AIncident%20Management%20Console27%2FDefault%20User%20View%20(Manager)9%2F3020872007%2Resolved%22%20AND%20((%27Assignee%20Login%20ID%27%20%3D%20%22Allen%22)Token=FEIH-MTJQ-H9PR-LQDY-WIEA-ZULM-45FU-P1FK HTTP/1.1"
100.100.100.100 - - [06/Nov/2018:10:10:10 -0666] "nothing that contains the trigger word"
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    if ($IS_Item -match 'login')
        {
        # build a custom object with the desired items
        #    the PSCO makes export to a CSV file very, very easy [*grin*] 
        # the split pattern is _very fragile_ and will break if the pattern is not consistent
        #    a regex pattern would likely be both faster and less fragile, but i can't figure one out
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            IP = $IS_Item.Split(' ')[0].TrimStart('**')
            Date = $IS_Item.Split('[}')[1].Split(':')[0]
            # corrected for not-really-there asterisks
            #LoginName = $IS_Item.Split('*')[-3]
            LoginName = (($IS_Item.Split(')')[-2] -replace '%\w{2}') -csplit 'ID')[1]
            }
        }
    }

# show on screen
$Results

# save to a CSV file
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\Henry_Chinasky_-_LogExtract.CSV" -NoTypeInformation
```

on screen output ...

```
IP            Date        LoginName
--            ----        ---------
192.168.100.1 13/Dec/2018 Allen
```

csv file content ...

```
"IP","Date","LoginName"
"192.168.100.1","13/Dec/2018","Allen"
```